# Is it possible to get ad campaigns related to one business manager through Facebook Graph API?

Tags: .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm working on .NET web application, and one of its feature is to keep track of Facebook ad's expenses and generated leads. There is many ad accounts - each representing business clients of my client, and all of them are connected within Facebook Business Manager. Is there a way to access all the campaigns at once, having access to Graph API by the business manager ?